# Select next "visible" sibling from the current row

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

A small selector with .next() jquery method is driving me crazy.

The story is like that, I am using Bootstrap filter with jquery on table rows. When the filter executes, it changes the display style attribute to table-row, like this:

```
 <tr class="activated" style="display: table-row;">
```

Now what all I want from Jquery is, select the next available TR, from the current TR, that has display = table-row.

I have tried with the following:

```
$(getSelectedRow()).next(":not(:hidden)") returns []

$(getSelectedRow()).next(":visible") returns[]

$(getSelectedRow()).next("tr[display==visible]") returns []
```

I want to use next because I want next first sibling.

Here is the HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover navigateable focused" id="bookmarkTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Bookmarks</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="searchable" id="bookMarkResultGridView">
            <tr class="activated" style="display: none;">
                <td class="word-wrap" data-rowindex="0" data-tabid="0"
                data-url="http://gitready.com/" style="cursor: pointer;">git
                ready » learn git one commit at a time<br>
                <small class=
                "text-muted word-wrap">http://gitready.com/</small></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="activated" style="display: none;">
                <td class="word-wrap" data-rowindex="1" data-tabid="0"
                data-url="http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en"
                style="cursor: pointer;">Codelab for Android Design Support
                Library used in I/O Rewind Bangkok session :: The Cheese
                Factory<br>
                <small class=
                "text-muted word-wrap">http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en</small></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="activated" style="display: none;">
                <td class="word-wrap" data-rowindex="2" data-tabid="0"
                data-url="https://github.com/rogerta/secrets-for-android"
                style="cursor: pointer;">Store your all Password in Android
                App<br>
                <small class=
                "text-muted word-wrap">https://github.com/rogerta/secrets-for-android</small></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="activated" style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="word-wrap" data-rowindex="3" data-tabid="0"
                data-url="https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout#design-support-library"
                style="cursor: pointer;">Google Play Style Tabs using TabLayout
                | CodePath Android Cliffnotes<br>
                <small class=
                "text-muted word-wrap">https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout#design-support-library</small></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your getSelectedRow() but if it can be swapped with some class selector (in this case i used .selected) and you would need only first next sibling that's not hidden this would be your solution:

```
$(".selected~tr:not(':hidden')").first();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r3f22uzn/

I'm not sure why this isn't working:

```
$(getSelectedRow()).find("~tr:not(':hidden')").first();
```

but this should work:

```
$(getSelectedRow()).find("~tr:not(':hidden')").each(function(){
    // first element
    $(this).css("background", "black")
    return false;
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r3f22uzn/3/

Comment: it will not give me the next sibling - instead it may return the same object where I am

Comment: I'm not sure if you checked jsfiddle, might be a browser issue that it's not supported or something, but you can clearly see there that it's selecting second visible sibling if you check it in firebug. Here's how it looks on my browser: http://imgur.com/GXITzJR  But I'm using that selected class, so that second example may not work.